# How to create a sticky navigation like SMINT for wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

Basically I want to use http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/ SMINT sticky menu including navigation thingy on Wordpress pages I've seen it done a million times with one page templates on themeforest, anyone have a clue to any plugin free or paid?

Or can show me how to put this into wordpress pages ? I tried but the js into the page doesn't work you can't include a js file.

I do not want to do this for the primary nav but sub navigation to scroll the content of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for the solution few days ago, I stumbled upon this post. I managed to resolve problem by creating custom Walker for nav menu using original Walker_Nav_Menu element output functions.

#### 1. Create walker class

Inside themes functions.php create new Walker class that extends original Walker_Nav_Menu. Copy original start_el and end_el element output functions code from / wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php (rows 68 – 187), and paste it inside custom Walker class.

```
class SMINT_nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu { 
   // copy original code from /wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php, rows 68 – 187
   // and paste here
}
```

After opening start_el function (orig. row 81) we will add code that will query posts object_id from global WPDB. These IDs we use as  link HTML output id that connects sections and trigger links. The original solution for querying is from this [topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13604/get-the-id-of-the-page-a-menu-item-links-to).

```
/* oppening start_el function */ 
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) { 

    /* Add code bellow to query posts object_id for <a> link HTML output id
     * source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13604/get-the-id-of-the-page-a-menu-item-links-to */
    global $wp_query;
    $pageid = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );

    /* and bellow continues original code with line */
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
```

Find `$atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';` (row 120 in orig.) and clear href link url by replacing `$item->url` with `'#'` so you get:

```
$atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ?     '#'           : '';
```

Finally we have to add post ID to nav link HTML output. Under`$item_output .=` (line 149 of original, just after line `$item_output = $args->before;`), edit  link by adding *id* class and calling post id from *$pageid* array.

```
/* SMINT SCROLL - Add post ID to link HTML output */
    $item_output .= '<a id="s' . esc_attr( $pageid ) .'"'. $attributes .'>';
```

#### 2. Add menu to theme

Call menu inside `<body> ... </body>` tags using:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('container_class' => 'smintMenu',
                        'walker'    => new SMINT_nav(),
    )); ?>
```

*'container class'* is default top menu class, and we have to define its name because we will use it as smint.js trigger element class.
Under *'walker'* we have to call custom Walker class we created previously.

#### 3. Load JS scripts

I'm still developing my theme, so I have loaded scripts directly inside header.php, just before closing `</head>` tag. For testing purposes I have loaded latest jquery.js, and jquery.smint.js from my themes js folder.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/themejs/jquery.smint.js"></script>

    <!-- activate smint -->
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('.smintMenu').smint({      // define class, same as 'class_container'
                'scrollSpeed' : 1000     // and scroll speed to 1000ms
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Don't forget to change the class in the activaction script accordingly to the one defined under *'container_class'*. In this example it's class *.smintMenu*.

That's it, refresh your web browser!

**Final remarks**

I have tested this on pretty naked theme under development, with only few lines of css and no other scripts that could conflict.
I have also played a little bit with including other wp_naw_menu parameters, and as long I kept *'container_class'* and *'walker'* defined as explained, SMINT worked fine.

I'll update with an example link when I complete the project.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the html structure of the nav, in that sample it looks like this:

```
   <div class="subMenu" >
    <div class="inner">
         <a href="#" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn active">Home</a> 
         <a href="#" id="s1" class="subNavBtn">What it does</a>
         <a href="#" id="s2" class="subNavBtn">How to use</a>
         <a href="#" id="s3" class="subNavBtn">Demo</a>
         <a href="#" id="s4" class="subNavBtn">Download</a>
         <a href="#" id="s5" class="subNavBtn end">About Me</a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

so to do so, you can `extend` wordpress class that control this.. ***this is sample, it may need more work***

```
<?php
class Create_cool_nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</div>\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'subNavBtn menu-item-' . $item->ID; //only in case you need it ?

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 's'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<div' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>'."\n";

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';


        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>'."\n";
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>'."\n";
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</div>\n";
    }

}
?>
```

After that we need to add the css..

```
 .inner {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 50px;
        padding:30px 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
.subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 462px;
    height: 50px;

    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 960px;

    background: #cdd242;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cdd242 0%, #74a34a 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cdd242), color-stop(100%,#74a34a));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #cdd242 0%,#74a34a 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #cdd242 0%,#74a34a 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #cdd242 0%,#74a34a 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #cdd242 0%,#74a34a 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cdd242', endColorstr='#74a34a',GradientType=0 );



}

.subMenu .inner {
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.subMenu {


    /*float: left;*/
}

/*.subNavBtn {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 50px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}*/

.subNavBtn {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 12%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 2% 0 2%;
    text-align: center;

    color: #3d3d3d;
}



.active {
    background: #fc0;
}
.end {
    margin: 0;
}
```

they are using [this plugin](http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/js/jquery.smint.js), there is another ways to do it. so you can include it like this, again in the `functions.php` file:

```
function add_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('migrate', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.1', false );
    wp_enqueue_script('smint', get_template_directory_uri().'/path/to/file/smint.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.1', false );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

finally lets add the `js` for make it work:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.subMenu').smint({
        'scrollSpeed' : 1000
    });
});

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
});
```

Test it and let me know, it may need to adjustments to make it work perfectly.

EDIT: i forgot.. lol how to use this in your template...

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu' => 'menu name', 
    'container' => false, 
    'menu_id' => 'subMenu',
    'walker' => new Create_cool_nav
));
```

Comment: sorry that seems a little too complicated.